# Android code is not finding the child in the Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, parent-child, exists

I would like to take a variable in Android, loop through the Firebase database, and check if there is any child in Firebase that is equal to the variable.
If it does not exist, prints that "The identifier does not exist". If it exists, do some action.

I wrote this simple source code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios");       
    if (!dataSnapshot.child("516d0a4e44ea877e798f26fb343d3d1e").exists()) {

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The identifier does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else { // Do some action
```

The problem is that Firebase is always reporting that the variable doesn't exist, even though it exists.

[image]

In the example above, there are childs written in MD5 code.
Even inserting the child: "516d0a4e44ea877e798f26fb343d3d1e", which you can see that exists in Firebase, it still says that the "child does not exist".
Please how to fix?

Comment: Where does this `onDataChange` code live in your app?

Comment: Thank you very much, Frank. I already achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child("516d0a4e44ea877e798f26fb343d3d1e");
if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The identifier does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} else { // Do some action

Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Please don't use block quote markings for code blocks. I already fixed that in your question, and recommend you apply the same formatting here: either indenting every line by 4 spaces + the amount of indentation the code needs, or by putting triple backticks on a separate line before and after the code block.

Comment: Thank you very much, Frank. I apologize for this. I didn´t know this.
Thank you.